# Changing the data type of the [hasMany:] reference to a list?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Is there a way to change the data type of the `static hasMany = [myList: Stuff]` definition in grails? I tried

```
List<Stuff> myList
hasMany = [myList : Stuff]
```

but my existing tests started throwing

`Stuff._MyContainer_mylistBackref; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value`

which indicates the two aren't equivalent in terms of how they're being handled. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Need more information about the exception context. `List` for `hasMany` used to work fine for me.

Comment: My should this behave differently than [myList : Stuff]? If I need a set, this works fine, leading me to believe the larger code segment is okay.

Comment: Isn't it that your myList is just set to null and never gets initialized? Shouldn't it read List<Stuff> myList = [] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in section [5.2.4 of the Grails manual](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.2.4%20Sets,%20Lists%20and%20Maps), this is the correct way to make the collection a `List`.

I suspect the problem is that by default the constraint `nullable(false)` is applied to all domain class properties and you're trying to save a null value for this property. To fix this, add a constraint that allows this property to be null (if that's what you want

```
List myList
static constraints = {
    myList(nullable: true)
}
```

Alternatively, make sure that the property is not null before the object is validated/saved.

Comment: I only ever use the addToMyList dynamic method, so shouldn't this be resolved automatically?