# nullable Grails hasMany list

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

im using grails 2.4.4. im new so I have a noob question probably
I have domain class like  this:

```
class E_PreguntaFrecuente {

static embedded=['perfiles','secciones','subsecciones']

String pregunta
String respuesta
Integer orden

static hasMany=[perfiles:E_Perfil,secciones:E_Seccion,subsecciones:E_Subseccion]

static constraints = {
    pregunta blank:false
    respuesta blank:false
    orden blank:false
    subsecciones nullable: true
}
```

}

I want the hasMany list of **subsecciones** to be nullable... how can I do that? I've tried what you see in the code; **subsecciones nullable:true** and some other variations like  putting **(nullable:true)** but none of them seem  to work, it keeps saying that the subsecciones list is required.

**edit**

I have no errors, just want to have a non required list...

here is an image of what I mean, i dont know if it can be nullable at save.. but i cant even pass the form part..

[image]

Comment: What does it mean `none of them seem to work`? Do you have an error on saving a certain object? Please add more informations.

Comment: I mean that it keeps saying its required... I'll edit.. ty

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5389126/3340702 and this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6943763/3340702

Comment: so, all your `hasMany` collections are also `embedded`? no further questions...

Comment: yes, all of them are also embedded

Comment: @lifeisfoo I tried those posts before posting my own, they did not work for me.. the list is still required

Comment: Why must they be embedded?

Comment: Why don't you just add the list property? Or add initial default value like `[]`? Could you post your controller action code?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa they are embedded because i want the whole json, im using mongoDB database... and i want to use it in  another web application

Comment: @lifeisfoo I added the list property like this: Set subsecciones = [], and  also  like  this: List<E_Subseccion> subsecciones = []... they work but i cant make it nullable... (i also have the hasMany even tho i declare as list as well)

Comment: Could you paste error messagees from your domain object? You can see them after a failed `save()`, using `yourObj.errors.allErrors.each {
        println it
    }` in the controller action

Comment: @lifeisfoo i have no errors, i can save succesfully, i just HAVE to save the subsecciones list... and i want it to be optional

Comment: If you don't have any errors during the save of an object with a null `subsecciones` field, I can't understand where is the problem. But wait, when you say "it keeps saying its required", who is the subject of the action? Are you talking about a message in the web page that appears when you try to save the object? Could you post your view data and a screenshot?

Comment: @lifeisfoo yes! its a web form  problem, but i think that is defined in the domain am i wrong?(im sorry im new in grails) then i execute a "generate-all" command...i updated the question with an image! thank you... PS, i dont know what you mean by "view data"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88523/discussion-between-juanmeza-and-lifeisfoo).

Answer (score 0):

so found a workaround, or maybe thats how its done, idk, im new in grails...
this is the generated  tag in the _form.gsp file:

```
<g:select name="subsecciones" from="${com.test.jwm.E_Subseccion.list()}" multiple="multiple" optionKey="id" size="5" required="" value="${e_PreguntaFrecuenteInstance?.subsecciones*.id}" class="many-to-many"/>
```

by removing the **required=""** attribute, it works as expected...

I just dont know how to configure the domain class so it gets generated that way... for other string variables it works with just **nullable:true** in the domain class... but well.. at least i found a workaround..

if anyone knows a better way, pls share